# Write text in a WebView from a socker reading in background

Tags: android, sockets, post, webview, handler

I have done a game in Android for 2 players using sockets.
When a player turns the screen I save sockes in a ViewModel, and restore then.
But if the player turns the screen when is waiting for the other player (reading stream):

- The screen is displayed right in onResume()
- When the read is done and I try to write the changes in the screen. The Webview loadData ignores it.
  -- I have tried with:

  ```
                    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ...
                        }
                    });
  ```

Does not fail... Does not work
-- And with `MutableLiveData<Object>` (not valid for background operations)

Can you give me some advise?...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was not able to access Graphic User Interface from a socked read from a Thread created and started at the OnResume method of a Fragment.
It received data from the socket, reached the WebView, called to loadData... but not updated the WebView!.
So... my solution was to declare the activity NOT TO BE DESTROYED, int the Manifest, in the activity tag, I set the attribute:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

The result is almost good. The view turns. But does not adapt to the size, like it where redrawn.